# Unable to request item data for Amazon in-app purchasing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, kindle-fire, amazon-appstore

I'm trying to set up in-app purchasing for the Amazon App Store, but am running into a problem when trying to request item data. I'm debugging on a Kindle Fire. Here's my code and what I see in LogCat:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    PurchasingManager.registerObserver( new AmazonPurchasingObserver( getActivity() ) );
    PurchasingManager.initiateItemDataRequest( SKU_SET );
}
```

LogCat output:

```
05-21 10:46:30.399: D/PurchasingManager(10474): In App Purchasing SDK - Sandbox Mode: PurchasingObserver registered: com.myapp.android.service.amazon.AmazonPurchasingObserver@406129f0
05-21 10:46:30.407: D/SandboxRequestHandler(10474): In App Purchasing SDK - Sandbox Mode: sendItemDataRequest
05-21 10:46:30.423: W/ActivityManager(1409): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.amazon.testclient.iap.itemData flg=0x10000000 (has extras) }: not found
```

So if the Kindle doesn't already have a service for the above intent, where is `com.amazon.testclient.iap.itemData`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Amazon includes a "AmazonSDKTest.apk" file in the tools directory of the zip that is downloaded. That needs to be installed on the device prior to testing in a sandbox environment.

Comment: it's actually called "AmazonSDKTester.apk", and it resides in the following directory
Android/InAppPurchasing/tools/AmazonSDKTester.apk

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem that I am able to run in app demo in sandbox mode but not able to run in live.